# Difference between recursive feature elimination and stepwise regression

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I have a dataset with 98 independent variables (or features in the multivariate machine learning case), 1 dependent variable (or target) with a N = 54.

Now I would like to explore which set of variables best predict the target variable.

I the first case I would run a stepwise regression to finally end with the set of variables that reaches the highest R2.

In the ML case I would run a recursive feature elimination with cross-validation to get the most important features using a support vector regression (also with criterion R2)

Could someone please explain me the difference between those two approaches and when to use which one ?

many thanks!, mike